# Determine Windows as 32- or 64bit

Tags: x86, 64-bit, autoit, cpu-architecture

This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
If FileExists(@HomeDrive & "Program Files (x86)") Then
   $arc = 64
Else
   $arc = 32
EndIf
MsgBox("Hello", "Bit", "The computer that the program is been run on is a " & $arc & "bit one.")
```

It will say my computer is 32bit when it is 64. So I had a look at the path and made new code:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
If FileExists(@HomeDrive & "Program Files (x86)") Then
   $arc = 64
Else
   $arc = 32
EndIf
$path = @HomeDrive & "\Program Files (x86)"
MsgBox("Hello", $path, "The computer that the program is been run on is a " & $arc & "bit one.")
```

This shows the path and seems to be OK. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the [`@OSArch`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/macros.htm) macro.

> Returns one of the following: "X86", "IA64", "X64" - this is the architecture type of the currently running operating system.

Comment: For the CPU architecture you should use the @CPUArch macro.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
if FileExists (@HomeDrive&"\Program Files (x86)") then
   $arc=64
Else
   $arc=32
EndIf
MsgBox("Hello", "Bit", "The computer that the program is been run on is a "&$arc&"bit one.")
```

Or this :

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
if FileExists (@HomeDrive&"\Program Files (x86)") then
   $arc=64
Else
   $arc=32
EndIf
$path=@HomeDrive&"\Program Files (x86)"
MsgBox("Hello", $path, "The computer that the program is been run on is a "&$arc&"bit one.")
```

Your code didn't work because you didn't put backslash check.

Answer (score -1):

> Does any one know where I am going wrong.

As per [Documentation - Macros](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/macros.htm):

> `@OSArch` Returns one of the following: "X86", "IA64", "X64" - this is the architecture type of the currently running operating system.
>
> `@CPUArch` Returns "X86" when the CPU is a 32-bit CPU and "X64" when the CPU is 64-bit.

Example:

```
Global Const $g_sTpl = 'OS  : %s\nCPU : %s\n'
Global Const $g_sMsg = StringFormat($g_sTpl, @OSArch, @CPUArch)

ConsoleWrite($g_sMsg)
```